# Separate nested arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I want to separate this array into multiple arrays depending on how many files there is.

```
Array
(
    [files] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => pic1.png
                    [1] => pic2.png
                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => image/png
                    [1] => image/png
                )

            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => C:\Windows\Temp\php893F.tmp
                    [1] => C:\Windows\Temp\php895F.tmp
                )

            [error] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                )

            [size] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 777180
                    [1] => 734111
                )

        )

)
```

I want it to look like this:

```
Array
(
    [files] => Array
        (
            [0] => array
                (
                    [name] => pic1.png
                    [type] => image/png
                    [tmp_name] => C:\Windows\Temp\php893F.tmp
                    [error] => 0
                    [size] => 777180
                )

            [1] => array
                (
                    [name] => pic2.png
                    [type] => image/png
                    [tmp_name] => C:\Windows\Temp\php895F.tmp
                    [error] => 0
                    [size] => 734111
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: 1) Why make the inner values an array if you want it to just store one value? 2) Thanks for telling us what you want, now tell us what have you tried?

Comment: I tried nesting foreach and counted with variables ($i, $i++)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your actual input array has the same structure and keys like that you provided in your question, then this piece of code should work:

```
$separated = array();

foreach ($array['files'] as $property => $values)
{
  foreach ($values as $key => $value)
  {
    $separated[$key][$property] = $value;
  }
}
```